# Role no mongodb não funciona

Tags: mongodb

criei 2 db e um usuario pra cada, porem o usuario 2 pode inserir dados no banco 1, o que estou fazendo errado

```
use shop
db.createUser({user: "appdev",pwd:"appdev", roles:["readWrite"]})
db.auth("appdev","appdev")
show collections
db.products.insertOne({name: "A book for appdev"})

db.logout()

use shop2
db.createUser({user: "appdev2",pwd:"appdev2", roles:["readWrite"]})
db.auth("appdev2","appdev2")
show collections
db.products.insertOne({name: "A book for appdev2"})
```

Ainda logado como appdev2, entro na db shop(que pertence ao appdev) e mesmo assim consigo inserir

```
use shop
db.products.insertOne({name:"i-am-appdev2"})
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedId" : ObjectId("5d8fdba878f7555a2060f1ec")
}
```

Porque ainda consigo inserir dados em uma collection que não é permitido?

Comment: Você está usando o builtin role [`readWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#readWrite) ele fornece  todos os privilégios de leitura, além da capacidade de modificar dados em **todas** as coleções não pertencentes ao sistema e na coleção [`system.js`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-collections/#%3Cdatabase%3E.system.js) para conseguir o seu objetivo você deve definir seus [próprios roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-user-defined-roles/#user-defined-roles).

Comment: @AugustoVasques creio que isso nao se aplica a versao 4.2, pois nao mudei as permissoes e apenas configurei o arquivo /etc/mongod.conf e tive o resultado esperado que eh de nao inserir ou ler collections de dbs que voce nao esta autorizado, senao o que voce esta dizendo nao faz sentido

Answer (score 2):

achei a resposta no stackoverflow em ingles.

Estou usando a versao do mongodb 4.2, tem que configurar no /etc/mongod.conf

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```